# PHP username check function not working

Tags: php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");

function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

I believe there is an error in the query because I always get "Username is taken" error, doesnt matter if I insert an existing username or not.

** SOLVED THANKS **

Comment: Can you copy the current error?

Comment: You haven't got $con defined in the function scope. You either need to pass it in with your function parameters, set up the connection within the function itself, or pass it in via a globally accessible class (such as $con = dbmanager::getConnection()).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) as user_id FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

`mysql_result` will not return you the result , it will send error so it gives you true always.

use below code to get result

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($row['user_id']){ return true; } else { return false; }
```

Comment: do not use `mysql_result` use `mysqli_fetch_array` check updated answer